# Python Requests Module Working on Windows Laptop but not on Ubuntu VPS

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, python-requests, vps

Python requests module to fetch json from a website works fine on my Windows laptop, but just refuses to run on my Ubuntu 20.04 VPS.

```
import requests
import json
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json'
headers = {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,hi;q=0.8,ml;q=0.7', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.87 Safari/537.36'}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
response = r.json()
print(response)
```

On Windows it executes in like a second, but on the Ubuntu VPS the code just stays on for like about 10-15 minutes and then throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 719, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 665, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 421, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1332, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 303, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 264, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TEST_requests.py", line 10, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, stream=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: Works fine on my Ubuntu 20.04 desktop maybe your VPS IP is blacklisted can you try another URL e.g. google.com

Comment: on VPS you could check if you can access this page - ie. `ping www1.nseindia.com` and better `wget https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json`

Comment: @furas I'm able to ping the website from the VPS. So it doesn't appear that the site is blocked. But on wget the outcome is similar to that of the python script, where it just hangs trying to fetch the data from the site. `Resolving www1.nseindia.com (www1.nseindia.com)... 23.37.45.217
Connecting to www1.nseindia.com (www1.nseindia.com)|23.37.45.217|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...`

Comment: @Dan-Dev I'm also using another python script to download reports (xls, csv & zip) from the site on my VPS without issues. So I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: For example `wget https://www1.nseindia.com/content/nsccl/fao_participant_oi_26062020.csv` works from the VPS.

Comment: I can access it in web browser and using your script but `wget` can't  access it. If I remove `user-agent` from script then I can't access it. Linux Mint 19.3 (on laptop)

Comment: you may try to use `Session()` and first get main page (or page on which load data from this JSON) to get Cookies. And later use this session (with cookies) to get JSON. You can check also if page whic load data from this JSON doesn't have other headers - ie. `Referrer` - which you could add to your request.

Comment: @furas I've tried adding `Session()` as you suggested. The updated code is as follows: 

`url = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/stock_watch/niftyStockWatch.json'
url2 = 'https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/equities_stock_watch.htm'
s = requests.Session()
s.get(url2)
print(s.headers)
r = s.get(url, headers=s.headers, stream=True)
response = r.json()
print(response)`

But outcome is the same. Still getting the `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))`

Comment: I would set headers in session - `s.headers.update(headers)` - to you then same headers in both requests. But maybe `nseindia.com` has your IP on blacklist (and maybe all IPs of your server provider) and you wll have to use some proxy servers - like [sslproxies.org](https://sslproxies.org/)